# Create a TypeScript interface for an array of mixed objects

Tags: typescript

I have an API ([Figma](https://www.figma.com/developers/api))that returns an array of mixed objects, where a fill can either be a solid color, or an image, like so:

```
{
  id: xxxxxxx,
  ...
  fills: [
    {
      blendMode: "NORMAL",
      imageRef: "xxxxxxxxx",
      scaleMode: "FILL",
      type: "IMAGE"
    },
    {
      blendMode: "NORMAL",
      color: {
        r: 1, 
        g: 0, 
        b: 0, 
        a: 1
      },
      type: "SOLID"
    }
  ]
}
```

The `fills` array can contain either, or both, fill types--or neither. How would I go about creating a TypeScript interface that can handle the above response?

Comment: `any[]`? Or when you say "neither" do you mean it can be _empty_? Where exactly are you stuck - do you have the types for the fills? Are you familiar with union types?

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbGO2W) meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, please [edit] the code in the question to show an unsatisfied use case.